# SQL convert - 2015-1 format date to 2015-01 format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar column with values like below

```
A
2015-4
2015-12
2015-9
```

I need the new column to look like

```
A
2015-04
2015-12
2015-09
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `stuff()`?

```
select (case when len(a) = 6
             then stuff(a, 6, 0, '0')
             else a
        end) as a
```

Or:

```
select (case when len(a) = 6
             then replace(a, '-', '-0')
             else a
        end) as a
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider casting it as a proper `DATE` and then formatting it via the [`FORMAT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function if your are using SQL Server 2012 and above :

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(YourColumn + '-1' AS DATE),'yyyy-MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (A varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (A)
VALUES
    ('2015-4'),
    ('2015-12'),
    ('2015-9')
;
```

Age Old Method :works in 2008 & above

```
select SUBSTRING(A,0,CHARINDEX('-',A))+'-'+
RIGHT('000'+CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(A),0,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(A)))) AS VARCHAR),2) 
from @Table1
```